What should I do if a brand new Android phone is overheating?
I brought 'Moto G24 Power' smartphone 2 days back. From day one it is overheating evening when I am doing basic tasks. I brought it from Flipkart online. There is no return, only repair from service center.
Is there any heating problem with this model or is it an hardware issue? What should I do?

Normal as per Moto help. Read for other things you can do

Heating is subjective. How hot?
